excelWB.write(fileOut); gives IllegalArgumentException
I am trying to use an excel to write the into new file using Apache POI. This is the method code,
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        XSSFWorkbook excelWB = null;
        try {
            String fileName = "C:\\Users\\frank\\Desktop\\Output\\test.xlsx"; 
            System.out.println("fileName: " + fileName);

            excelWB = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet = excelWB.createSheet("PartList");

            XSSFRow headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
            headerRow.createCell(0).setCellValue("Type");

            XSSFRow dataRow = sheet.createRow(1);
            dataRow.createCell(0).setCellValue("0th column");
            dataRow.createCell(1).setCellValue("1st column");

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            excelWB.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //assert excelWB != null;
            excelWB.close();
        }
    }
}

It is giving me the warning as below
14:24:12.172 [main] WARN org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper - SAX Feature unsupported [log suppressed for 5 minutes] http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalStylesheet
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalStylesheet
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.setAttribute(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:571)
    at org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.trySet(XMLHelper.java:283)
    at org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.getTransformerFactory(XMLHelper.java:224)
    at org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.newTransformer(XMLHelper.java:230)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.StreamHelper.saveXmlInStream(StreamHelper.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipContentTypeManager.saveImpl(ZipContentTypeManager.java:68)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.save(ContentTypeManager.java:450)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:563)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1490)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:227)
    at Scratch.main(20240726.excel.hata.java:27)


Not reproducible with POI v 5.2.2; please [edit] your question with version information; +1 for [mre].

For reference, I used these dependencies.

I checked my jars. Names are poi.jar, poi-ooxml.jar, poi-ooxml-lite.jar in my dependencies. The jars you have has version numbers in their names like poi-5.2.2.jar. But when I check the MANIFEST.MF files under my jars, they have Implementation-Version: 5.2.2 written. @trashgod

I can't explain your finding; you might check your dependencies against the Component Map noting ooxml plus either lite or full (but not both).

there was a fix in POI 5.2.3 - https://github.com/apache/poi/commit/9b60986f682ad3a23f3e5d4f19ddd645879ad8bb - I would recommend trying the latest versions of the libs (eg 5.3.0), bugs do get fixed from time to time
